# Haproxy with SSL and shared session

Tags: session, ssl, shared, haproxy

Actualy I testing the latest dev version of haproxy with the native ssl support. It works fine but  I've have a question. Does the shared ssl sessions are available like with Stud? 
If the answer was true, how can I setup her? 
I didn't find this in the haproxy documentation...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sessions can be shared between multiple processes but not yet multiple hosts. However, the developer who did the job for Stud did it with haproxy in mind and he's also the one who did the multi-process cache, so in theory it should not take long to him to finish this, provided of course that we don't enter new nasty issues when dealing with UDP listeners :-)

Comment: Yeah good news! Don't forget to implement unicast for the update exchanges please. Well, I need to be patient now.